# django.utils.formats.date_format returning messy result

Tags: python, django, date, format

In Django 1.11, given a datetime.datetime object, e.g.

```py
datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 24, 16, 50, 5, 685162, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Bucharest' EEST+3:00:00 DST>)
```

I am trying to format it to `24.08.2023` by invoking:

```py
from django.utils.formats import date_format
date_format(date, 'NUMERICAL_DATE_FORMAT')
```

Instead of the expected result, I get:

```py
Aug.1692885005AugAugustR1CPMFalse_ThuPMEESTAugust_August+0300RAugPMEEST
```

As per [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files), I've defined `NUMERICAL_DATE_FORMAT = 'd.m.Y'` in my `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sees `'NUMERICAL_DATE_FORMAT` just as the formatting string, so it will start with `N`: the short name of the month (`Aug.`), `U` the unix timestamp (`1692885005`), etc., you need to *import* it from the settings, so:

```
from django.conf import settings

date_format(date, settings.NUMERICAL_DATE_FORMAT)
```